# In which cases Shannon entropy is a convex function of a distribution parameter?

Tags: partial-derivative, covariance, positive-semidefinite, exponential-family

Given a discrete random variable $\xi\colon\Omega\rightarrow X$, $\left| X \right| < \infty$ with a probability distribution depending on a parameter $\theta\in\Theta=\Theta_1\times...\times\Theta_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ and a function $f\colon X\times\Theta\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ -\inf \right\}$ that is double differentiable by the second parameter, namely
$$
P_{\xi}(x; \theta)=\frac{\exp{f\left(x, \theta\right)}}{Z\left(\theta\right)}, \\
Z\left(\theta\right) = \sum_{x\in X} \exp{f\left(x, \theta\right)},
$$
I would like to know whether its Shannon entropy is a convex function of $\theta$.

If my calculations are correct, then the second derivative of the entropy is
$$
\frac{\partial^2 H_{\xi}\left(\theta\right)}
     {\partial\theta_j \partial\theta_i}
=
  cov_{\xi}\left(
    \frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_j},
    \frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_i}
    \cdot \left(
      E_{\xi}f\left( \xi, \theta \right)
      + f\left( \xi, \theta \right) + 1
    \right)
    + f\left( \xi, \theta \right)
    \cdot E_{\xi}
      \frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_i}
  \right) \\
  - cov_{\xi}\left(
    \frac{\partial^2 f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}
         {\partial\theta_j\partial\theta_i},
    f\left( \xi, \theta \right)
  \right).
$$
If the second derivative of $f$ is a constant, I still cannot tell anything about positive semidefiniteness unless I can tell in which cases
$cov_{\xi}\left(\frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_i}, f\left( \xi, \theta \right) \right)$ and $cov_{\xi}\left(\frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_i}, \frac{\partial f\left( \xi, \theta \right)}{\partial\theta_i}\cdot f\left( \xi, \theta \right)\right)$ form positive semidefinite covariance matrices, because in this case I obtain a sum of positive semidefinite matrices, which is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Are there researches on this topic, am I losing something obvious, or is this a really complicated question depending on the specific case?